# Performance Regression Testing / Load Testing on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, load-testing

What tools or best practices exist to demonstrate a new server instance is "as capable" as an older one?

We're moving from an EC2 hosted instance of MS SQL Server to an RDS instance, and have been tasked with "proving" that the new platform won't cause any regressions.

The naive idea is to somehow replicate a day's worth of load, and record the elapsed time for all the queries. Then, if the worst 0.1% of the queries run no slower, we're good.

Is that logic good, or is there a flaw, or is there a better/standard way?

What would I need to do on the old server to "capture" a day's worth of load? (Queries, parameter values, session id so that I can simulate the correct number of concurrent connections, login name, elapsed query time, etc).

What else am I missing?

(Another niave idea was to put a "load balancer" on to "replicate" the queries to both instances, and log the query times. Is that even possible?)

Answer (score 4):

This is 100% a valid approach. However, sadly, there's no really simple way to make it happen.

To start with, you're going to need to capture the query metrics for your existing servers. The two best mechanisms are either Query Store (enabled by database, so it's not a full server measure, ever) or Extended Events. Extended Events gets detailed metrics and you can measure everything happening on a server (just be prepared, that's a lot of data).

The next step is to figure out a way to replay the events. Microsoft had a tool, Distributed Replay. Sadly, it never got much support and is now on the [deprecated list](https://www.scarydba.com/2022/08/15/distributed-replay-the-little-engine-that-almost-could/). You can still make it work, but it is a true pain in the bottom.

To get around this, I'd suggest using a combination of DBATools ([excellent support for Extended Events](https://dbatools.io/xevents/)) and Gianluca Sartori's [WorkloadTools](https://spaghettidba.com/tag/extended-events/). It's going to be a bunch of work to set this up, but between these two tool sets, you can get it done.

Comment: I like RML Utilities for workload capture and replay. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103126

Comment: But they only officially support up to 2014. Plus, trace... yuck.

Comment: What only supports up to 2014?  Not RML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/replay-markup-language-utility

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Is there a guide you can recommend for its use anywhere?  I can't find anything beginner friendly.  I also tried SQL Profiler's REPLAY ability, but can't get past `Failed to set proper user name ('username') for the connection`.  Is RML related?

Comment: Honestly it's not a really "beginner-friendly" tool.  It was created and is maintained by and for the SQL Server support team.  The documentation is all in the download, such as it is.  You might find the Database Experimentation Assistant easier to use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-overview?view=sql-server-ver16  OStress from RML is the "built-in" replay tool for DEA.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I'm not convinced that works on Amazon RDS, it's requiring me to be sysadmin, which Amazon RDS doesn't appear to allow.

Comment: If you can create XEvent traces and restore databases you should be able to work around not being a sysadmin.